# swift for loop working in Playground but not in the real code

Tags: for-loop, swift

I have started using Swift: Version 6.0 (6A313)

As a newbie with Swift, I try both Playground and real code. It baffles me that this simple code works in a Playground but not when I put it into the class I want it in:

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    for i in 1...3 {
        println(i)
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

}
```

Error message: "Expected declaration".

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs to be inside a function, for example:

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    func doSomething() {
        for i in 1...3 {
            println(i)
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise there's no way to call this code, and no indication of when / how you expect it to run.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to thank you! But your answer did solve my issue. Thanks again.